# UIActivityViewController equivalent in WatchOS

Tags: swift, watchos

I am wondering whether WatchOS8 has something similar to UIActivityViewController for sharing content to other apps (either SwiftUI or WatchKit)

If there is something even remotely similar I am interested to know

Thanks

Alexis